# How should I handle two QGLWidgets which only share the same shaders?

Tags: qt, opengl, pyqt, pyopengl

I've just added a second QGLWidget to my app (both QGLWidgets  inherit from the same class). While the first one still works as expected, the second one raises a GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY, in the glDrawArrays() method of my paintGL()method, whatever the data which filled the buffers

I manage to solve this in adding the first QGLWidget as a "share widget" when creating the second one:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qglwidget.html#QGLWidget

However, now, it seems that the two QGLWidgets are linked/synchronized (especially the camera but only when switching to a widget to another).

My question is thus more general as I would like to know how I should handle my two QGLWidgets, to avoid conflicts, knowing that they only share the same shaders code (vertex and fragment) but no data (they do not write/read the same buffers).

EDIT: I use PyQt4

Comment: Does using Qt5 (QOpenGLWidget instead of QGLWidget) could solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes to the fact that when I switch from a window to another (my GLWidgets being on different windows), the paintGL() method is called and, as the context is share, they also share the same camera matrices. Thus, at the beginning of each paintGL() method I call my updateCamera() method.